# Sorting Fraction? Selection Sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

There are two java classes named `Array` and `Fraction`. `Fraction` class is used to represent a ratio of two integers. There are accessor(getter) and mutators(setter) methods and other methods that allow the user to set the numerator and the denominator. Also included a method to display the fraction on the screen as a ration (e.g 5/9).

`Array` class allows the user to create array of 7 fractions. Then the program will sort the fraction in ascending order. Then maximum and minimum fractions are thrown away and the remaining fractions are added together. The program should display all the fractions and their sum. The sum should be reduced to the lowest terms.

Assume there are 7 fractions,

- 6/7, 2/4, 3/18, 1/8, 10/20, 2/6, 3/4.

After Sorting

- 1/8, 3/18, 2/6, 2/4, 10/20, 3/4, 6/7

Remove minimum and maximum fractions then get the sum of the rest

- 3/18 + 2/6 + 2/4 + 10/20 + 3/4 = 9/4

I'm confused on how to sort the "fractions" in the `Array.java` class. I have named it selection sort. As well, how do I throw away the lowest and the largest fractions?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Array {

    public static void selectionSort(Fraction[] arr)
    {}

    public static void setFraction(Fraction[] arr)
    {
        Scanner scan  = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=0;
        for (Fraction e : arr)
        {
            i++;
            System.out.println("Input Numerator: " + i + " of 7");
            e.setNumerator(scan.nextInt());

            System.out.println("Input Denominator: " + i + " of 7");
            e.setDenominator(scan.nextInt()); 
        }
    }

    public static Fraction addFraction (Fraction x, Fraction y)
    { 
        int gcd = 0;
        Fraction sum = new Fraction();
        gcd = x.getDenominator() * y.getDenominator();

        sum = new Fraction(x.getNumerator() * y.getDenominator() + 
                x.getNumerator() * y.getDenominator() +  y.getDenominator() * x.getNumerator(), gcd);
        return sum;
    }

    private static final Scanner keyb = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fraction fr[] = new Fraction[7];
        String reduce = "";
        Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in); 

        for (int i =0; i< fr.length; i++)
            fr[i]=new Fraction();

        Array.setFraction(fr);
        Array.selectionSort(fr);

        Fraction sum = Array.addFraction(fr[0], fr[1]);
        for (int i =0; i <fr.length; i++) {
           fr[i].display();
           if(i<fr.length-1) {
               System.out.print(" + ");
           }

        }

        System.out.print(" = ");
        sum.display();
    }
}
```

Here is `Fraction`:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Fraction {
    public static int length;
    public int numerator = 1;
    public int denominator = 1;
    public int gcd;
    public Fraction() {
        super ();
    }
    public Fraction(int n, int d) {
        numerator = n;
        denominator = d;
    }
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.print(numerator +"/" + denominator);
    }
    public int getNumerator() {
        return numerator;
    }
    public void setNumerator(int numerator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
    }
    public int getDenominator() {
        return denominator;
    }
    public void setDenominator(int denominator) {
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }
    private static int gcd(int numerator, int denominator) {
        return denominator == 0 ? numerator : gcd(denominator, numerator % denominator);
    }
    public double decimal(double numerator, double denominator) {
        return numerator / denominator;
    }

    public static void reduce(int numerator, int denominator) {
        int gcd = gcd(numerator, denominator);
        numerator /= gcd;
        denominator /= gcd;
        //return (numerator / gcd) + "/" + (denominator / gcd);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return numerator + "/" + denominator;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `Fraction`? where does it come from?

Comment: In brief, selection sort is, keep on iterating through the list of data, and pick up the largest one from the list, remove it and put in a result list.  Keep doing until you empty the original list.   We can use the original list as the "result list" (see the link for example).  Of course in order to sort a list, you need to be able to "compare" two elements to see which one is bigger.   The rest (figure out how to compare two fractions, implementation of sort) are your own works to do.

Comment: @chatlover : You have mentioned that there are 7 fractions. But in your example there are 6. I guess 3/4 is missed. And after sorting minimum and maximum values are ignored and get the summation of the rest. Isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, yes! There should be seven here. The minimum and maximum are suppose to be ignored, then to get the summation from the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Before using selection sort, you have to perform some extra work i.e. 

1. First of all, try to make denominator of all the fractions to be equal i.e. LCM of denominator by multiplying each fraction with some value.

2. And, use the same value to multiply with its numerator part.

3. After, second step your denominator is same, so now you can apply selection sort on the basis of numerator. Ans , also readjust the value by dividing with corresponding constant value used in step 1.

Comment: If you pick seven random `int` values to be the denominators of your fractions, how likely is it that their LCM will be small enough to fit in an `int`?